# Activating the animation of one part of a page by clicking an image in another part

Tags: javascript, html, css

After sifting through a bunch of forums and questions on stackoverflow, it seems to me that using JavaScript is a unavoidable here. I have successfully implemented an animation of a list on my site, but I would like the animation to only play after an image has been clicked (and then to close it by clicked again).

This is the animation:

```
.scale-in-hor-left {  -webkit-animation: scale-in-hor-left 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) both;
  animation: scale-in-hor-left 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale-in-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes scale-in-hor-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

And the image I would like to activate it has nothing special going on

```
<img id="imagename" src="#" height="#" />
```

I know the JavaScript looks something like this:

```
function ani(){
    document.getElementById('imagename').className ='scale-in-hor-left';
  }
```

But every time I try some HTML to use the two together, I just end up with a button or nothing, and I have yet to get the animation to stop before the click. (Also, will successfully getting the `onclick` to work ensure that the animated element is invisible before activation based n the `0%`s in the CSS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in thinking that you'll want to control the animation with a `click` event handler; otherwise, as you're seeing, your CSS animation kicks off immediately.

As written, your `ani()` function will only *add* your animation class to your target "list" element. You will need to toggle the class name on 'click' to alternately add *or* remove it. To do that, the event handler needs to determine which action to take.

Assuming that you're attempting to accomplish this in vanilla JavaScript (that is, you aren't using a library like jQuery — which has a [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method of its own), you can use the presence of the class name itself to determine this…

```js
var
  CLASSNAME_TOGGLE = 'toggle-class',
  el_trigger = document.getElementById('trigger'),
  el_target = document.getElementById('target');

function toggleClass(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (el_target.classList.contains(CLASSNAME_TOGGLE)) {
    // remove the class
    el_target.classList.remove(CLASSNAME_TOGGLE);
  } else {
    // add the class
    el_target.classList.add(CLASSNAME_TOGGLE);
  };

}

el_trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleClass, false);
```

```css
#target {
  /* this would be your list's default styles */
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fbb;
  background: #fee;
}

#target.toggle-class {
  /* this would be your list's animation */
  border-color: #bfb;
  background: #efe;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  Your "List" Element [the target of the toggled class]
</div>
<img id="trigger" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x50?text=Your+Trigger+Image" />
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a detailed response!! I am literally a day into this whole coding thing, so I am trying to understand as best I can. For the target id, can I just slap the #target { bit right over my div class for my list (called menu in my code)? 

if it helps, what I'm working on is visible [here](https://codepen.io/brxtn/pen/byeMgO)

Comment: Your markup (the HTML) has some underlying issues. Seemingly small mistakes — like closing an `<img>` tag with a `</input>` — are going to introduce HTML validation/rendering issues that will confound your efforts. It looks like you are new to Stack Overflow; **Welcome!** One of the recommended practices for asking questions here is to [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help isolate your issue so we can help. The practice itself is often revelatory; as you pare down your code, you may find the assumption/typo/mistake yourself.

Comment: That said, do you see that in your click handler: `$("#menuleaf").click(function() { $("#menuleaf").addClass("scale-in-hor-left"); });` — `$("#menuleaf")` is both the trigger *for* the action **and** the target of the `.addClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

If your okay with using jquery then:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$("#imagename").click(function() {
 $("#imagename").addClass("scale-in-hor-left");
});
```

Or with vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementById("imagename").addEventListener("click", ani); // This calls your function ani
```

Comment: Would my HTML be like this then?
```
<div id="scale-in-hor-left"><img src="#"></div>
```